# Pandas Dataframe Groupby Determine Values in 1 group vs. another group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Date        ID
2014-12-31  1
2014-12-31  2
2014-12-31  3
2014-12-31  4
2014-12-31  5
2014-12-31  6
2014-12-31  7
2015-01-01  1
2015-01-01  2
2015-01-01  3
2015-01-01  4
2015-01-01  5
2015-01-02  1
2015-01-02  3
2015-01-02  7
2015-01-02  9
```

What I would like to do is determine the ID(s) on one date that are exclusive to that date versus the values of another date.

> Example1: The result df would be the exclusive ID(s) in 2014-12-31 vs. the ID(s) in 2015-01-01 and the exclusive ID(s) in 2015-01-01 vs. the ID(s) in 2015-01-02:

```
   2015-01-01  6 
   2015-01-01  7
   2015-01-02  2
   2015-01-02  4
   2015-01-02  6
```

I would like to 'choose' how many days 'back' I compare. For instance I can enter a variable `daysback=1` and each day would compare to the previous.  Or I can enter variable `daysback=2` and each day would compare to two days ago.  etc.

Outside of `df.groupby('Date')`, I'm not sure where to go with this.  Possibly use of `diff()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the "Date" in your DataFrame is: 1) a date object and 2) not the index.

If those assumptions are wrong, then that changes things a bit.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def find_unique_ids(df, date, daysback=1):

    date_new = date
    date_old = date - timedelta(days = daysback)

    ids_new = df[df['Date'] == date_new]['ID']
    ids_old = df[df['Date'] == date_old]['ID'] 

    return df.iloc[ids_new[-ids_new.isin(ids_old)]]

date = datetime.date(2015, 1, 2)
daysback = 1

print find_unique_ids(df, date, daysback)
```

Running that produces the following output:

```
        Date  ID
7 2015-01-01   1
9 2015-01-01   3
```

If the Date *is* your Index field, then you need to modify two lines in the function:

```
ids_new = df.ix[date_new]['ID']
ids_old = df.ix[date_old]['ID']
```

Output:

```
            ID
Date          
2015-01-01   1
2015-01-01   3
```

EDIT:

This is kind of dirty, but it should accomplish what you want to do. I added comments inline that explain what is going on. There are probably cleaner and more efficient ways to go about this if this is something that you're going to be running regularly or across massive amounts of data.

```
def find_unique_ids(df,daysback):

    # We need both Date and ID to both be either fields or index fields -- no mix/match.
    df = df.reset_index() 

    # Calculate DateComp by adding our daysback value as a timedelta
    df['DateComp'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda dc: dc + timedelta(days=daysback))

    # Join df back on to itself, SQL style LEFT OUTER.
    df2 = pd.merge(df,df, left_on=['DateComp','ID'], right_on=['Date','ID'], how='left')

    # Create series of missing_id values from the right table
    missing_ids = (df2['Date_y'].isnull())

    # Create series of valid DateComp values. 
    # DateComp is the "future" date that we're comparing against. Without this
    # step, all records on the last Date value will be flagged as unique IDs.
    valid_dates = df2['DateComp_x'].isin(df['Date'].unique())

    # Use those to find missing IDs and valid dates. Create a new output DataFrame.
    output = df2[(valid_dates) & (missing_ids)][['DateComp_x','ID']]

    # Rename columns of output and return
    output.columns = ['Date','ID']
    return output
```

Test output:

```
         Date  ID
5  2015-01-01   6
6  2015-01-01   7
8  2015-01-02   2
10 2015-01-02   4
11 2015-01-02   5
```

EDIT:

```
missing_ids=df2[df2['Date_y'].isnull()] #gives the whole necessary dataframe
```

Comment: thanks, this looks promising, but is there a way to do it for a whole dataframe  with many dates?  Like the example?  To be clearer, I would like the result dataframe to be the combination of the two examples above (I will edit)...

Comment: Yep, added a new option above that will apply the same logic to the entire df.

Comment: Nice work.  THis does work.  I enhanced your answer further (I believe) by changing your missing_ids and using pandas groupby function, eliminating the need for valid_dates.  See EDIT.  This is the accepted answer and +1!  Thanks.

Comment: Take that back, no need for groupby, see my edit though, create dataframe of isnull and can avoid valid_dates part.

Answer (score 1):

Another way by applying list to aggregation,

```
df
Out[146]: 
          Date  Unnamed: 2
0   2014-12-31           1
1   2014-12-31           2
2   2014-12-31           3
3   2014-12-31           4
4   2014-12-31           5
5   2014-12-31           6
6   2014-12-31           7
7   2015-01-01           1
8   2015-01-01           2
9   2015-01-01           3
10  2015-01-01           4
11  2015-01-01           5
12  2015-01-02           1
13  2015-01-02           3
14  2015-01-02           7
15  2015-01-02           9

abbs = df.groupby(['Date'])['Unnamed: 2'].apply(list)

abbs
Out[142]: 
Date
2014-12-31    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
2015-01-01          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2015-01-02             [1, 3, 7, 9]
Name: Unnamed: 2, dtype: object

abbs.loc['2015-01-01']
Out[143]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

list(set(abbs.loc['2014-12-31']) - set(abbs.loc['2015-01-01']))
Out[145]: [6, 7]
```

In function

```
def uid(df,date1,date2):
    abbs = df.groupby(['Date'])['Unnamed: 2'].apply(list)   
    return list(set(abbs.loc[date1]) - set(abbs.loc[date2]))


uid(df,'2015-01-01','2015-01-02')
Out[162]: [2, 4, 5]
```

You could write a function and use date instead of str :)

Comment: This also looks promising.  Can you give an example of the function and how to apply to the groupby?

Comment: this does work, but not in many date cases without explicit definition of dates.  @cggarvey's answer works for every case.  still plus 1 as it does answer question.